A tower of fields $k \subseteq L_1 \cap L_2 \subseteq L_i \subseteq F$ with $[F:L_i] < \infty$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$
Let $k \subseteq L_i \subseteq F$ be two towers of fields, $1 \leq i \leq 2$.
Denote $n_i=[F:L_i]$, $m_i=[L_i:k]$ and $l=[F:k]$.
Asssume that the following conditions are satisfied:

$n_1,n_2 < \infty$.

$\gcd([F:L_1],[F:L_2])=\gcd(n_1,n_2)=1$.

$m_1=[L_1:k]= \infty$, $m_2=[L_2:k] = \infty$ (hence $l=[F:k]=\infty$).

The field generated by $L_1$ and $L_2$ is $F$.


We have, $k \subseteq L_1 \cap L_2 \subseteq L_i \subseteq F$.

Question 1: When $L_1 \cap L_2 =k$? (In this case $[F: L_1 \cap L_2] = \infty$).


Question 2: When $[F:L_1 \cap L_2] < \infty$?

For example: $k=\mathbb{C}$, $L_1=\mathbb{C}(t^\frac{1}{2})$, $L_2=\mathbb{C}(t^\frac{1}{3})$, $F=\mathbb{C}(t^\frac{1}{6})$, $n_1=3$, $n_2=2$, $\mathbb{C} \subsetneq L_1 \cap L_2 =\mathbb{C}(t)$, so $[F: L_1 \cap L_2]=6$.
Thank you very much!
The motivation for asking the above question is the following situation: $k \subseteq E_1 \cap E_2 \subseteq E_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$ assuming $[E_i:k] < \infty$ and $\gcd([E_1:k],[E_2:k])=1$. Then $[E_1 \cap E_2:k]$ divides both $[E_1:k]$ and $[E_2:k]$ which are co-prime, hence $[E_1 \cap E_2:k]=1$, so $E_1 \cap E_2 =k$.
I am looking for a condition similar to $E/K$ is field extension. $L_1,L_2$ are intermediate fields. $[L_1L_2:K]=[L_1:K][L_2:K]$ implies $K=L_1\cap L_2$.
